# How can I pass an array to the server when using $http?

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have an array of ids that I want to pass to the server. The other answers I have seen online describe how to pass these ids as query parameters in the url. I prefer not to use this method because there may be lots of ids. Here is what I have tried:

AngularJS:

```
console.log('my ids = ' + JSON.stringify(ids)); // ["482944","335392","482593",...]

var data = $.param({
    ids: ids
});

return $http({
    url: 'controller/method',
    method: "GET",
    data: data,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
.success(function (result, status, headers, config) {
    return result;
})
```

Node.js:

```
app.get('/controller/method', function(req, res) {
    console.log('my ids = ' + JSON.stringify(req.body.ids)); // undefined
    model.find({
        'id_field': { $in: req.body.ids }
    }, function(err, data){
        console.log('ids from query = ' + JSON.stringify(data)); // undefined
        return res.json(data);
    });

});
```

Why am I getting `undefined` on the server side? I suspect it's because of my use of `$.params`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rest `GET` methods uses the URL as the method to transfer information if you want to use the property `data` in your AJAX call to send more information you need to change the method to a `POST` method.

So in the server you change your declaration to:

`app.post(` instead of `app.get(`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ExpressJS server-side, `req.body` only contains data parsed from the request's body.

With `GET` requests, `data` is instead sent in the query-string, since [they aren't expected to have bodies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body).

```
GET /controller/method?ids[]=482944&ids[]=...
```

And, the query-string is parsed and assigned to [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.query) instead.

```
console.log('my ids = ' + JSON.stringify(req.query.ids));
// ["482944","335392","482593",...]
```

Comment: Is there a limit on how much data I can send via this method? My concern is that it will break if I am sending a large number of ids.